# How to optimize the loading of your apps resources?

Tags: android, optimization, resources, load

Im starting to approach the end of my game, and need to worry about loading resources efficiently since they are starting to add up (Bitmaps, sounds etc). 
When should an android app load its resources to optimize performance?

For example I initiate all my bimaps and sounds in my custom views constructor, that gets started when you press "new game" in my menu (my menu is the main activity).

Is there any way to load these bitmaps during startup (splashscreen) so the user doesnt experience lag during the first seconds of gameplay, is the only way by uncluding my splash and menu in my game-loop and using states, instead of starting up an activity?

Answer (score 1):

Create a thread that does the loading separate from the thread that does the running. The running thread can then monitor to see when loading is done. The user can then see a loading screen or some animation (or just the title screen) to indicate nothing is freezing while things load in the background.